# Permission denied error while deleting the directory from HDFS using JAVA API

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have tried to delete the directory using the following method,

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
fs.delete(new Path("path/to/file"), true);
```

But am facing the permission denied error, Is this possible to solve?

I tried the following solution but it is not working,

```
dfs.permissions=false in hdfs-site.xml
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission to delete that directory?  That is to say, whatever use the app is using, does it have permission to delete that directory?

Comment: I have used su to delete the directory while running the MapReduce via script. But I tried to delete the HDFS directory from my application by using the above method it is not working

Comment: Is this an actual HDFS directory, or a local directory?

Comment: Also, if you have to use `su` or `sudo` to delete something, it means that your user account *does not* have permission to delete it.

Comment: Probable source of confusion: HDFS has a concept of users and file permissions which is independent of the users and permissions at the OS level. And it sounds like you're having trouble with the OS permissions.